# Подмена HTTP REFERER

Tags: php

сообствено вопрос таков, допустим есть сайт "мойсайт.ру" из него нужно перейти на сайт "другойсайт.ру" если просто сделать переход по ссылке то на сайте "другойсайт.ру" в глобалке referer будет "мойсайт.ру" вопрос как подменить referer что бы там после перехода был не мой сайт, а скажем к примеру "сайт3.ру"

Буду очень благодарен за ответ, уже второй день ломаю голову ничего толком не получается. Спасибо.

Comment: В браузере - никак.

Comment: просто подставить нужный урл в заголовке; `CURLOPT_REFERER` https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: @Lexx918 А можете написать пример рабочего кода, просто я еще новачок учусь только? Буду очень благодарен с меню плюс в репу